# md-autocomplete disable esc function from raising

Tags: angular-material, md-autocomplete

the suggestion dropdown disappears when user clicks the input then press esc key.
then a weird progress bar keeps cycling..
I need to disable this function

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add an id or a class in your `md-autocomplele`. Then, try this:

```
#id md-progress-linear .md-container
{
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
.class md-progress-linear .md-container
{
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with this error one entire day, but the solution is simple: **update your angular-material library**.

*More information? Version 1.1 work fine. If you look the solution is here: https://github.com/angular/material/commit/e821ae327f4ed193d14450aa0c83cd457092f563 (line 446 of autocompleteController.js)*